# Multiple traversing of records in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a scenario where I want to traverse through records for same Client in a table.

My table structure is:

[image]

My current query is producing the last service ID and the first service ID. However, I want the result to be as below:

[image]

```
create table #temp1(cid int,cvid int, date1 date, clone int)
insert into #temp1
values ('43','1001','1/1/2015',null),
        ('43','1002','2/1/2015',1001),
        ('43','1003','3/1/2015',null),
        ('43','1004','4/1/2015',1003)

create table #person(cid int)
insert into #person values(43),(44),(45)


select top 1 with ties
    t.cid
    ,t.cvid
    ,clone = (select max(t2.cvid) from #temp1 t2 )
    ,t.date1
from #temp1 t
order by row_number() over (partition by cid order by date1)


drop table #temp1,#person
```

Rextester link: https://rextester.com/NQNB22767

Any help?!

Comment: hi rick -- have you tried anything yet?  typically we don't just write the code but fix something.

Comment: Your sample data seems very simplified. Is the relationship always a single one-to-one chain? How many levels could it go? What does the expected output look like if something has grandparents? Great grandparents? etc...

Comment: @Hogan Rick did try something, but it's buried in the rextester link.

Comment: @AaronBertrand the levels are not predefined. It's so dynamic. So levels cannot be defined. But I want to pull out the last cloned service along with its parent

Comment: Word problems are hard. Add these rows to your sample data and then show desired results: `('43','1005','3/1/2015',null),('43','1006','4/1/2015',1005),('43','1007','5/1/2015',1006)`

Comment: So I will add more data to the test data link and update it in a min. There is no such pattern followed.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I have added more test data to the sample table and added the picture here. Link also edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like it's producing the desired results...

```
    CREATE TABLE #temp1 (
        cid INT,
        cvid INT,
        date1 DATE,
        clone INT
    );
    INSERT INTO #temp1(cid, cvid, date1, clone) VALUES
        ('43', '1001', '1/1/2015', NULL),
        ('43', '1002', '2/1/2015', 1001),
        ('43', '1003', '3/1/2015', NULL),
        ('43', '1004', '4/1/2015', 1003),
        ('43', '1005', '4/2/2015', 1004),
        ('43', '1006', '4/3/2015', 1005),
        ('43', '1007', '4/5/2015', NULL),
        ('43', '1008', '4/6/2015', 1007);

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ixf_temp_notclone
    ON #temp1 (clone, cvid)
    INCLUDE (cid, date1)
    WHERE clone IS NULL;

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ixf_temp_clone 
    ON #temp1 (clone)
    INCLUDE (cvid)
    WHERE clone IS NOT NULL;


    WITH    
        cte_recursion AS (
            SELECT 
                t.cid,
                t.cvid,
                pid = cvid,
                t.date1,
                t.clone
            FROM
                #temp1 t
            WHERE 
                t.clone IS NULL
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 
                r.cid,
                r.cvid,
                pid = t.cvid,
                r.date1,
                t.cvid
            FROM
                cte_recursion r
                JOIN #temp1 t
                    ON r.pid = t.clone
            )

    SELECT 
        r.cid,
        r.cvid,
        clone = MAX(r.clone),
        r.date1
    FROM
        cte_recursion r
    GROUP BY 
        r.cid,
        r.cvid,
        r.date1;
```

Results:

```
cid         cvid        clone       date1
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------
43          1001        1002        2015-01-01
43          1003        1006        2015-03-01
43          1007        1008        2015-04-05
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is helpful. I tried something similar with CTE but because my dataset was so huge, the run time was so long. Which was the reason to drop this idea

Comment: Unfortunately, there really isn’t a better way to traverse an adjacency list hierarchy. The other options are a while loop & fast forward cursor. No matter which option you take, the key is to make sure you have the proper indexes in place. 
I’ve updated my original code to include two filtered indexes. With these in place the multiple table scans are replace with index seeks. Note that the benefits of the first will be negligible compared to the second. The first one will be used once but the second will used for every iteration of the recursive loop.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has the standard olap functions FIRST_VALUE() and LAST_VALUE(), I think this would be better than ROW_NUMBER().